# Join Multiple Rows in Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I've got multiple rows in my result from my query:

for example, the table "extras":

```
id_extras - id_order - id_size - name_extra - price

1           1          3         Teddy        4
2           2          8         Balloon      8
3           2          9         Wine         2
4           2          1         Choco        9
5           6          1         Bag          4
```

What I actually want is:

```
id_extras - id_order - id_size - name_extra - price - name_extra1 - name_extra2 - price1 - price2

1           1          3         Teddy        4
2           2          8         Balloon      8       Wine          Choco         2        9
3           6          1         Bag          4
```

So i need the `name_extra` and `price` to be in columns instead of rows, i have this up now.

```
SELECT  * ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN id_order = id_order THEN name_extra ELSE NULL END) name_extra1,
                MAX(CASE WHEN id_order = id_order THEN name_extra ELSE NULL END) name_extra2,
                MAX(CASE WHEN id_order = id_order THEN price ELSE NULL END) price1,
                MAX(CASE WHEN id_order = id_order THEN price ELSE NULL END) price2
FROM    extras 


GROUP   BY id_order
```

Comment: Why do you need it that way? That makes no sense and doesn't scale as you don't know how many items are in an order until you query the database.  What happens when there are 10 items in an order?

Comment: If SQL Server, you're talking about PIVOT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx. I often argue you don't need it: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/06/forget-about-pivot/

Comment: You tagged this with both sql server and mysql, what database are you using?

Comment: it's for MYSQL and i need this because im working in a BACKUP and RESTORE using LOAD DATA INFILE and the structure is different in the DB im Restoring